# Psycopg2 can't adapt type 'tuple' issue occurring intermittently

Tags: python, django, postgresql, psycopg2

Recently we upgraded Django & Python version to following

**Python 3.9.5, Django 3.2, Psycopg2 2.9.1, Httpd 2,4.2, Postgres 12.8**

Observed that the Application was failing intermittently with `psycopg2.ProgrammingError: can't adapt type 'tuple'` error

Below are the Query and Params logged before the `cursor.execute()` is executed

`{'employer_id': 200176, 'approximate_age_band': ('30-39', '50-59')`

```
SELECT month_key as cadence_val, sum(eligible_count) as eligible
    FROM xyz_table_name 
    WHERE employer_id = %(employer_id)s      
    AND approximate_age_band IN %(approximate_age_band)s GROUP BY 1 ORDER BY 1;
```

Below is complete stacktrace

```
2021-10-27 05:00:52,280 [ERROR] django.request: Internal Server Error: mobile_report/reports
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/www/pulse_preprod/service/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: can't adapt type 'tuple'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/www/service_rest/service/api/views.py", line 375, in mobile_visits
    data = get_report_data(request, "VisitsReport", src_employer_id)
  File "/var/www/service_rest/service/api/views.py", line 453, in get_report_data
    data = get_data(src_employer_id, filter_params, report_key, **params)
  File "/var/www/service_rest/service/api/views.py", line 466, in get_data
    data = report_obj.get_data(employer, filter_values, **params)
  File "/var/www/service_rest/service/reports/pulse/mobile.py", line 49, in get_data
    rows1, cadence_list = self.get_rows_from_query(cursor, sql1, employer_id, table_name,
  File "/var/www/service_rest/service/reports/__init__.py", line 1415, in get_rows_from_query
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/var/www/pulse_preprod/service/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 66, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "/var/www/pulse_preprod/service/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 75, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "/var/www/pulse_preprod/service/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/var/www/pulse_preprod/service/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/var/www/pulse_preprod/service/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.Error: can't adapt type 'tuple'
```

**During multiple attempts the request is working fine few times (returning the expected data from DB) but throwing this error randomly.**

That kinda rules out python dependency or psycopg2 extension or DB data issues right?

Any help is appreciated.

Code is scattered across multiple methods but pasting the gist

```
from django.db import connection

cursor = connection.cursor()

sql2 = """SELECT month_key as cadence_val, sum(eligible_count) as eligible FROM xyz_table_name WHERE employer_id = %(employer_id)s AND approximate_age_band IN %(approximate_age_band)s GROUP BY 1 ORDER BY 1;"""

age_param = ['30-39', '50-59']  #List of strs from request body
params  = {'employer_key': 200176, 'approximate_age_band': tuple(age_param)}

cursor.execute(sql, params)
rows = cursor.fetchall()
```

**Update:**

1. One more observation is that the requests are working fine for
   initial few hours when the Httpd service is restarted.
2. Other queries which do not have any tuple based params are working fine all the time

Comment: what is the value of `'approximate_age_band'` when it throws these errors

Comment: That param is a tuple with value ('30-39', '50-59')

Comment: Could you add the part of the code where you call out/execute the SQL query?

Comment: The code is scattered across different methods but the base is                     
 ```from django.db import connection

cursor = connection.cursor()
sql = """SELECT month_key as cadence_val, sum(eligible_count) as eligible
    FROM xyz_table_name 
    WHERE employer_id = %(employer_id)s      
    AND approximate_age_band IN %(approximate_age_band)s GROUP BY 1 ORDER BY 1;"""

age_param = ['30-39', '50-59']  #List of strs request body
params  = {'employer_id': 200176, 'approximate_age_band': tuple(age_param)}

cursor.execute(sql, params)

rows = cursor.fetchall()```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest fix, would be to use `approximate_age_band` as list:

```
cur = connection.cursor()

values = {'employer_id': 200176, 'approximate_age_band': ['30-39', '50-59']}

query = """select *
from test t
where t.approximate_age_band = ANY(%(approximate_age_band)s)
"""
print(cur.mogrify(query, values).decode('utf-8')) # Show the executed SQL statement
cur.execute(query, values)
print(cur.fetchall())
```

Out:

```
select *
from test t
where t.approximate_age_band = ANY(ARRAY['30-39','50-59'])
[
  (None, None, 420, 509, '50-59'), 
  (None, None, 210, 508, '30-39')
]
```

Comment: Thanks @maurice-meyer for the suggestion. Will try this solution. But I am still confused about what could cause the issue to happen randomly. All requests work fine for few hours after restarting the app but then this issue starts.